# Updating tables in sql

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, update

I've made this procedure to update the fields on a table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE actualizarEncargadosP(
OID_EN2  IN encargadosp.oid_en%TYPE,
nombre2 IN encargadosp.nombre%TYPE,
apellido2 IN encargadosp.apellido%TYPE,
email2  IN encargadosp.email%TYPE)
IS 
BEGIN 
UPDATE EncargadosP 
SET nombre = nombre2, apellido = apellido2, email = email2  
WHERE OID_EN = OID_EN2;
COMMIT WORK; 
END actualizarEncargadosP; 
/
```

The problem is that this way forces me to update every field, I'm looking for a way to be able to update the fields that I need in that moment.

Comment: `CREATE PPOCEDURE ... ( ..., value_filedX, ... , update_fieldX BOOLEAN, ...) ... UPDATE ... , fieldX = CASE WHEN update_fieldX = True THEN value_filedX ELSE fieldX END, ...`. Or the same transferring NULL in `value_filedX` new value: `... fieldX = COALESCE(value_filedX, filedX), ...`.

Comment: Something like this???: `SET nombre = CASE WHEN nombre2=True THEN nombre 2 ELSE nombre END`

Comment: No. Your query text must be synthactically correct.

Comment: Does nombre, apellido and email are NULLable? if not - does it is possible that the field must be altered and new value is NULL?

Comment: They are not nullable, and no, what I want it to do is that when executing the procedure, if some fields '', it will leave the old data. Example: `execute actualizarEncargadosP (20 '', '', 'New email')`  That should only change the field email, leaving nombre and apellido unchanged but not null.

Answer (score 0):

> > Does `nombre`, `apellido` and `email` are NULLable? - Akina
>
> > They are **not null**able – user198683

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE actualizarEncargadosP ( OID_EN2  IN encargadosp.oid_en%TYPE,
                                  nombre2 IN encargadosp.nombre%TYPE,
                                  apellido2 IN encargadosp.apellido%TYPE,
                                  email2  IN encargadosp.email%TYPE )
IS 
BEGIN 
UPDATE EncargadosP 
SET nombre = COALESCE(nombre2, nombre), 
    apellido = COALESCE(apellido2, apellido), 
    email = COALESCE(email2, email)  
WHERE OID_EN = OID_EN2;
COMMIT WORK; 
END actualizarEncargadosP;
```

When a field must be altered you transfer non-NULL according parameter.

When a field must NOT be altered, you transfer `NULL` in according parameter.

Comment: FYI - You can use procdure's name to reference the desired scope of variables such that you don't need the `2` suffix    eg `actualizarEncargadosP.OID_EN`.

Comment: @MichaelKutz Tell this everything to OP. I post his code with minimal edition, for to eliminate the problem only.